# How to set Cargo configurable-env setting for specific profile?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to use [`configurable-env`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/config.html#env) Cargo feature to set environment variables specific to a certain profile.

```toml
# Instead of global version:
# [env]
# FOO_QTY = "10"

# Something similar to the following(pseudocode):
[profile.test.env]
FOO_QTY = "2"

[profile.release.env]
FOO_QTY = "1000"
```

Comment: *Perhaps `[target.'cfg(debug_assertions)'.env]`?* EDIT: Nevermind, [apparently "There is currently no way to add dependencies based on these configuration values."](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly your question, but you can create a `static` or `const` that's set based on the profile.

```rust
pub const FOO_QTY: usize = if cfg!(build = "release") {
    1000
} else {
    2
};
```

Presumably you're trying to conditionally configure some value or behavior (at least that's how I found this question). The [`cfg!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.cfg.html) is a more flexible way to do that.